# JPA using @PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa

How to get the Persistence Unit Name dynamically?

For example in below example,I am hard coding `unitName` to `application_openjpa`, but I want to give it dynamically as `unitName=#{unitName}` so if I have different project uses the entity jar, but can use its own `persistence.xml` file

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="application_openjpa")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an application normally have limited number of persistence units, how about create two setter methods and annotate it with different unitName attribute, eg:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="testEM")
public void setTestEntityManager(EntityManager testEM) {
  this.testEM = testEM;
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName="prodEM")
public void setProdEntityManager(EntityManager prodEM) {
  this.prodEM = prodEM;
}
```

Then you can choose between `testEM` and `prodEM` dynamically ?